# Drush migrate-upgrade error

Tags: drush, migrations

I have run `drush migrate-upgrade` successfully previously, but not when I run it, I am getting

> "An option named "Configure-only" already exists."

I get this error regardless of if I have `--configure-only` in the command.

The command is:

```
drush migrate-upgrade --legacy-db-url=mysql://user:password@localhost/db --legacy-root=http://example.com --configure-only
```

Has anyone seen this error?  I am not seeing anything on any forums about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by uninstalling and reinstalling all of the migrate-related modules.  Not an ideal solution, but it worked.